# Is it correct to say "is it (a bag of chips) finished?" to mean that it's out of chips?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

The person is eating out of a bag of chips in front of me and I want to ask if the bag is out of chips now when he grabs a handful. Can I simply say—

> Is it finished?

And can I use it for other things as well that come in packages or bottles (for eg a bottle of soft drink)

I searched online but I could only find 'finish' used with food, meal, jam or the like.

Comment: Is your bag of chips finished? :)

Comment: In my experience, it would be more common to ask, "Is anything left?" Many variants are used, though.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK we usually ask,

> All gone?

This is what we ask our children even before they can talk.

The unabbreviated question might be,

> Are/have they all gone?

or, for a bottle,

> Is/has it all gone?

These might also be used by someone who feels they didn't get their fair share.

Bags of chips are rare in formal situations, but perhaps,

> Have you finished?

would be the least *in*formal question, or maybe,

> Are they finished?

Very informally (and usually if **each** of you has a bag),

> How are you doing?

can be used to ask for a progress report.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I looked up some examples and came across this one. I'll paraphrase it—`A: I'm going to have some of those chips. B: They're gone.` Out of context, would you think that the chips are gone for some other reason (stolen maybe)? Or does it by default imply they've been eaten?

Comment: I don't know where you found the example or how you have paraphrased it. English is used IN context. Discovering that someone has stolen your chips (or your diamonds), you might exclaim, "They've gone!" or perhaps "They're gone!": _either_ is possible, but the exclamation mark is **essential**. In certain circumstances  a friend, a starving man, a naughty child, a seagull, someone looking at a menu, or in (or going to, or entering) a shop might say, "I'm going to have some of those chips", but out of context...? Your example doesn't imply anything "by default". It isn't idiomatic.

Comment: The example was from Custody Battles by Gregory Ashe. And the conversation took place in the kitchen with the next dialogue being "Colt finished them? That's fine. I'll open the other bag." It's just that I'm new to this phrase so I didn't readily attach the meaning of "eaten up" to it. But it's clear to me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user17121: You're welcome. And welcome to the group! :-) Context, or a link to the quoted text if it's online, always helps!